# Map Filtered XML to an Excel Table

Tags: excel, xml, vba, filter

I have the below code that maps an XML Schema to Excel Tables (as in ListObjects).

```vb
Sub MapXMLFieldsToExcelCells(wb As Workbook, sLOB As String)

'*******************************************************************
'**    Name:        xmlFieldMap
'**    Purpose:     Maps fields of existing xlmMap (named "xmlData") to file
'**    Dependents:  TieXMLToExcel (remapping of xml file)
'**    Notes:
'*******************************************************************

sProcName = "MapXMLFieldsToExcelCells"

With wb

    Dim xMap As XmlMap
    Set xMap = .XmlMaps(sLOB)

    Dim wsXMLMain As Worksheet

    Set wsXMLMain = .Worksheets("xml" & IIf(Left(.Name, 2) = "SA", "SA", "") & sLOB)

    Dim wsConfig As Worksheet
    Set wsConfig = .Worksheets("rConfig")

    With wsConfig

        Dim rNode As Range
        For Each rNode In .Range("xmlNodeMapping").Columns(1).Cells

            Dim sNodePath As String
            sNodePath = rNode & rNode.Offset(, 1)

            Dim sTable As String
            sTable = rNode.Offset(, 2)

            'only have this here in case node does not exist
            'caveat is that it will fail also if node is just written out wrong
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'On Error Resume Next
            wsXMLMain.ListObjects(sTable).ListColumns(rNode.Offset(, 3).Value2).XPath.SetValue xMap, sNodePath
            'On Error GoTo ErrorReport
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Next

    End With

    .XmlMaps(sLOB).DataBinding.Refresh

End With

End Sub
```

*(please ignore project specific lines here - there are not too many)*

The code works great. I can map nodes and attributes of nodes if I pass a configuration sheet like this:

```
Xpath           Node    Table   Field
/root/d/p/t/    ar      tForms  AR
/root/d/p/t/    @n      tFormsa name
```

What I would like to do, if it's possible, is to apply a filter on a node to only map certain elements of that node.

For example, based on correct syntax:

```
Xpath                       Node        Table   Field
/root/d/p/t[item='ar']/     type        tForms  type
```

Would only pull elements from node t that = ar.

I can't get this to work and can't find anything online. I could accept is that is not an option but wanted to ask before giving up on the approach.

Comment: [This old forum thread](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/full-xpath-support-in-visual-basic.2336295/) pointed to an MSDN article which listed restrictions on the XPath predicates that could be used with XMLMaps in Excel 2003. The link in the thread is dead but the article can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203724(v=office.11).aspx#odc_xl_excel2003xmlintro_mappingranges). No idea if this is relevant for more recent versions of Excel though

Comment: Surely you been around SO a while, can we see some data (xml data, schema file) for a reproducible example?

Comment: @Parfait - Fair point :). I will do my best to upload sample data in coming days. Very busy with work at the moment.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - An unanswered question upvoted 7 times draws some attention to it.
Although an older post, I'd appreciate your editing some complementary xml data & a schema file very much. Hopefully for (some) answers, too :-)

Comment: Can you throw the data through regex and work off of that?